# Error 404: Not Found Fuseki

Tags: fuseki, apache-jena

This is my first time using `Apache Jena Fuseki 2.4.0`. I'm trying to run my friend's ontology website, he said that he's using `Apache Jena Fuseki` so I need to install it first but, when I already installed it and then I ran a server and typed his website on address bar, I got this error

> 404: Error 404: Not Found Fuseki - version 2.4.0

. Here are the steps that my friend told me I need to follow.

1. I downloaded `Apache Jena Fuseki 2.4.0`
2. I unpacked it to directory `C:\`
3. I launched `fuseki-server.bat`
4. I went to `http://localhost:3030/`
5. I clicked Manage Datasets menu
6. I clicked Add New Dataset button
7. I typed "DOID" as `Dataset Name` and chose "Persisten" as `Dataset Type` and then I clicked Create Dataset
8. I clicked Upload Data and I selected `doid.owl` file, and then I clicked Upload Now
9. When the upload was successful, I ran my friend's website and got that error

Is there any wrong or missing step that I took? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, suddenly it works! I tried to follow the set up from this [site](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/permissions/example.html):

1. I downloaded some jars and then I edited `fuseki-server.bat`
2. I tried to comment and uncomment some line but, because I couldn't launch `fuseki-server.bat` at all after that, so I decided to undo a change on `fuseki-server.bat`
3. I launched `fuseki-server.bat` again but the command prompt disappear after the process has finished
4. I checked `http://localhost:3030/` the server status was green and I tried to run my friend's website and then it worked!

I guess that the jars I've downloaded are the things that make it works.